# Escaping string parameters in Django templates for a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a JavaScript function which returns a set of objects:

```
return Func("{{id}}", "{{name}}")
```

I have a problem with passing strings containing quotes, for instance `"Dr.Seuss' "ABC""BOOk""` is invalid syntax.

I tried `{{name|safe}}` but to no avail. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm right in assuming that's a JavaScript function call you're trying to interpolate Django templating into, try the `escapejs` filter instead of `safe`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs

Comment: I was looking for that for one hour... How happens that for me (like the OP), the escape tag didn't escape the quote/double quote like his example of : "Dr.Seuss' "ABC""BOOk"" ?