# how can i extract from my django model into a javascript variable (Django)

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views

How can I extract data from my django model and put it into a javascript variable. I have a music player that uses javascript, within the JS code there is a variable 'trackUrl' which is a list of the track paths. How can i use my music model to extract the track and place into this JS code ? I've been trying to find a solution but was only advised to use Django REST framework, is there another method I could use. Could you please explain in detail as I'm still learning Django. Thanks

This is the music player : https://codepen.io/himalayasingh/pen/QZKqOX

models.py

```
class Music(models.Model):
    track = models.FileField(upload_to='path/to/audio')
    title = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    artwork = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', blank=True)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
@login_required 
def music_upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MusicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            song = form.save(commit=False)
            song.artist = user
            song.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Track Uploaded')
            return redirect('my_profile')
    else:
        form = MusicForm()
    return render(request, 'feed/music_upload.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Giving data from your DB to your frontend can be achieved in many ways. You can add context variables in your views or you can fetch them via Rest framework and Ajax. If you want the path in your music_upload.html you could `music_paths=Music .objects.all()` and then add `music_paths ` to your context like you did with `({'form':form, 'music_paths': music_paths}` in your template you can now call {{music_paths}}. or use a for loop to get each one individually

Comment: will {{music_paths}} work in the Javascript code of the music player ?

Comment: The best thing in the beginning is just trying stuff out and googling. If you use {{music_paths}} in your js it will likely throw an error. You can google this error and then will find something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647307/escaping-string-parameters-in-django-templates-for-a-javascript-function you will try it out and search for the next solution. Please don't hope for "here is everything you need solutions" if you want to make it in programming a little "hands on mentality" won't hurt

Comment: One Trick must be to put {{music_paths}} value into a global variable in the html page inside a <script></script> and then access it from your js code